# How can I schedule task with celery which runs at the end of month?

Tags: python, celery, cron

I need to set celery crontab to run at the end of month even different day as end of month(28~31).
I know how to set crontab run at the end of month on shell command like this:

```
55　23　28-31 * * /usr/bin/test $( date -d '+1 day' +%d ) -eq 1 && exec something
```

But on celery schedule I don't know how to do this setting. 
Is there any way to schedule task which runs at the end of month on celery?
It seems only way is to override `is_due` method on `celery.schedules.crontab`.

Comment: Does anybody know solution?

Comment: I found the way which is editing is_due method on celery.schedules.crontab. Is this only way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a bit of overhead - you can set the task to run every day in CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE.

And then in the task itself you can check if the day is the last day of the month:

```
import calendar
from datetime import datetime

@task
def task_to_run_at_end_of_month():
    today = datetime.today()
    day_in_month = today.day
    month = today.month
    year = today.year
    day_of_week, number_of_days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(year, month)
    if day_in_month != number_of_days_in_month:
        # not last day of month yet, do nothing
        return
    # process stuff on last day of month
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Celery comes with a [module](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules) that does exactly this.

The way to run it from the command line is like this

```
celery -A $project_name beat
```

Where normally you would use `worker` instead of `beat`

Then include in your `celery_config.py` a definition of the `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE`. Something like this

```
from celery.schedules import crontab

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
        "end_of_month_task": {
            "task": "module.task_name", # this is the task name
            "schedule": crontab(0, 0, day_of_month=0),
            "args": the_arguments_to_this_function
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. I tried your code but I got invalid corntab error:
 `ValueError: Invalid crontab pattern. Valid range is 1-31. '0' was found.`     
I use celery version 3.1.

Comment: Agh, you're right. I thought this code was using the builtin `crontab` class, but it is actually a custom class overriding the `is_due` method.

Comment: Could you tell me a link or code that is a custom `crontab` class?